# "Recursive update" while mocking classes for Micronaut unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, micronaut

I am building unit tests for my application and getting circular dependency issues that I have no explaination for.

Specifics of my app - it uses some @Context beans with @PostConstruct functions that spawn some threads.
Because of that I dont want them in my unit tests, so I am unsing following approach - 
create a @Replaces subclass also overriding the function that is performing the @PostConstruct stuff(othervise it still triggers the unvanted Thread spawning).

You (I) cannot use @MockBean on @Context bean - they still initialize...
Also I am mocking another bean with @MockBean, at this point problems start - I am getting now some kind of circular dependency issue :

```
Message: Recursive update
Path Taken: MockHandler.senderService --> SenderService.apiClient --> WithContextMockTest.toBeTestedClass --> ToBeTestedClass.apiClient
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1174)
```

I have here a minimal build created to repeat this issue:
https://github.com/Aziris/MicronautRecursiveUpdate

I see no reason why there is link **SenderService.apiClient --> WithContextMockTest.toBeTestedClass** at all, as the "apiClient" (class RestClient in example) has no dependencies.

If I take out of equastion my @Context class (make it regular @Singleton bean) this issue does not appear any more.
I suspect that there must be better way to mock the @Context beans, but I dont know any more options.

Any ideas what is so terribly wrong in the sample project ?

Answer (score 2):

I have now one answer to my own question, but I am not sure if there are ways to still solve it differently.

One answer to this particular issue would be - define interfaces and inject by interface, not by class name.

I wonder if injection by class is illegal or it just has some bug in Micronaut handling ?
The application itself runs well also if you inject the class, only @MicronautTest test classes get into trouble.